# IIS ISAPI error DelphiXE7

Tags: delphi, iis, delphi-xe7

Server 2008
IIS 6.0
Delphi XE7

I am getting an error when I read from a stream into a TWICImage on my dll.

**Error
Access violation at address 75DB59B5 in module 'ole32.dll'. Read of address 0000000D**

```
WIC:=TWICImage.Create;
Innstream:= TmemoryStream.Create();
 Try
  // Line below gets a stream from Amazon 
  ok := ass.GetObject(bucket,folder+'/'+filnavn,Innstream, nil);
  Innstream.Position:= 0;
  wic.LoadFromStream(Innstream); // This line create the error
  from_image.Assign(Wic);
```

**wic.LoadFromStream(Innstream); // This line create the error**

If I setup same code in a VCL exe application it works ok , so I guess its my dll missing access to something

any idea ?

Comment: What happens in `ass.GetObject`?

Comment: I am downloading a image as a stream from Amazon S3 to Innstream Tmemorystream

Comment: The download works is the LoadfromStream that raises the error

Comment: What I meant was can we see that code? Because I'm guessing that's where your problem is.

Comment: Nope its not the error happen in wic.LoadFromStream(Innstream);

Comment: That may not be where the error message happens but it may be where the source of the error happens. Why do you refuse to show it? What if it downloaded something different than what you expected? How have you confirmed that the download works? Because I see nothing in your code above that could possibly give an error.

Comment: The very best advice one can give at this point is probably to eliminate the unnecessary stuff and just try the simplest version: Eliminate the `ass.GetObject` call and replace the `TMemoryStream` by a file stream, to read the `folder+'/'+filnavn` file directly. Does that work? The error message loks very much like a null pointer, so my guess would be that the memory stream data (or maybe the initial file data) are corrupt when you feed them to `LoadFromStream`. BTW, did you call `CoInitialize()` somewhere?

Comment: And also: Check if it works in a simple desktop/command line program instead of within an ISAPI.

Comment: Hi , thanks for all comments. I have tested the code moved it to  a standard VCL  app exe file , all works fine.  After I sat up a new server, and now the dll is working , must be some rigths needed on Loadfromstream in ole32.dll or something in the setup of ISS , anyway a new server fixed the problem.